# both method append(Object) in StringBuilder and method append(char) in StringBuilder match

Tags: java, string, append, stringbuilder

reference to append is ambiguous
rez.append(ROOT_FORM.containsKey(text.charAt(i)) ? ROOT_FORM.get(text.charAt(i)) : text.charAt(i));
^
both method append(Object) in StringBuilder and method append(char) in StringBuilder match

how to resolve that this error after migration java 7 to 8

```
public static final String removeAccent(String text) {
        text = preProcess(text);
        StringBuilder rez = new StringBuilder(text.length());
        for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++) {
            rez.append(ROOT_FORM.containsKey(text.charAt(i)) ? ROOT_FORM.get(text.charAt(i)) : text.charAt(i));
        }
        return rez.toString();
    }
```

Comment: What does `ROOT_FORM.get(text.charAt(i))` return?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.